# How to copy .war file to another directory with maven?

Tags: file, maven, deployment, ant, copy

I need copy the .war file that I build from target directory to deploy directory. I know how to do it with Ant but in this project use Maven and I dont know how to make it.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Misunderstanding Maven. Maven is a build tool and not a deployment tool. May be you can take a look at [Cargo Maven Plugin to deploy to Tomcat/Whatever...](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html)

Answer (score 3):

In the War plugin configuration, you will need to give the plugin an output directory.  ex:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>[the name you want for your war file]</warName>
        <outputDirectory>[the output directory you want the war in]       </outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Just replace the brackets and text with what you want

Answer (score 2):

I believe the previous answer *places*, not copies, the WAR file with the specified name to the specified directory. So the WAR file does not appear in the default target/ directory. I tried adding a second  block in hopes Maven would put the file in both directories and this caused Maven to ignore the first.